# Results with exactly 4 small letters a

Tags: mysql, regex

From MySQL table `town` I have to find number of all names containing 4 SMALL letters a

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `town`
where `name` REGEXP
```

I just need that REGEXP. Anyone?

Comment: Do you want it to match `aaaa`, `aAaBaCaD`, `ABCaaaa`, `aaaaBCD`, what?

Comment: query like that is case insensitive

Comment: `.*[aA].*[aA].*[aA].*[aA].*`

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I want exactly that

Comment: Wow, so many downvotes and on the other side so many wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
a{4}
```

should find all occurrences of 4 consecutive a's.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result

Answer (score 1):

a non regexp solution is possible as a long shot:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `town`
where length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, 'a', 5)) = LENGTH(name)
and length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, 'a', 5)) > 3
```

Comment: no, that is case insensitive

Comment: fixed by adding collate clause

Comment: Close but still not right. Now I'm getting also towns with more than 4 `a`'s

Comment: used substring_index to limit to just 4 a's

Comment: Rene, thank you very much for your answer. Inside my result list, somehow, there are `Aarau Postauto Aargau` `Sta. Maria in Calanca` and few more towns with more than 4 `a`s

Answer (score 1):

`a.*a.*a.*a` would find all occurences that contain at least 4 `a`'s

`a{4}` would find all with four consecutive a's

`[aA].*[aA].*[aA].*[aA]` is a case insensitive version of the first.

`[aA]{4}` is a case insensitive version of the second.

Regex is not needed here and is unnecessary overhead use LIKE '%a%a%a%a%' instead if possible. Props go to rene who i stole this from.

Answer (score 0):

This was the question on my test. Now we've got the answer

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `town`
where
`name` REGEXP BINARY '^([^a]*a[^a]*){4}$'
```

or

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `town`
where
length(`name`) - length(replace (`name`,'a', '')) = 4
```